# How to use jQuery .on() method declaring grouped events to recognize future elements?

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have the following structure:

**HTML**

```
<select name="var" id="myselect">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>  
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$("#myselect").on({
    click: function(){
        console.log("event click fired!");
    },
    change: function(){
        console.log("event change fired!");
    }
});
```

The events aren't firing because the `select` is being created dynamically after the page load.

Someone knows how to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to recognize future elements with grouped events?

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/rP7EN/)

Comment: The change event fires after you leave the select in some browsers, and when you choose an option in others.

Comment: You might also want to look into the 'input' event.

Comment: @dystroy, I've updated the question, please take a look

Comment: @KevinB, Please take a look in my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/rP7EN/).

Among the things that can go wrong for you :

- you don't import jQuery
- your script is called before the HTML (simply put your script at the end of your body)

If you can't put your script at end of the body, enclose it in a ready event handler :

```
$(function(){
 $("#myselect").on({
    click: function(){
        console.log("event click fired!");
    },
    change: function(){
        console.log("event change fired!");
    }
 });
});
```

EDIT :

If the select is created dynamically, use this :

```
$(document.body).on('click', "#myselect", function(){
     console.log("event click fired!");
}).on('change', "#myselect", function(){
     console.log("event change fired!");
});
```

Note that you might replace `document.body` by a selector of an element that exists when you call this code and that will contain the select.